# How to disable and enable button in angular at http call?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing angular application on angular 6, i have multiple form which has submit button as well, when ever user submits i need to disable the button and enable it once get response, i have multiple form in the same page so the button disable/enable should work independently.

So what i want is create a mapping between the button and http response to track it, and the response should say which button i have to enable.

Any logic- how to create directive for that ? Below code work's for one form alone.

Thanks in advance...

in my template:

```
<button [disabled]="disabled"> Submit<button>
```

In my .ts

```
this.disabled = true;

this.http.get(...).subscribe((r) => { this.disabled = false });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your issue a little bit more?

Comment: how do you manage disabled property of every form submit btn?

Comment: You need to have a property, e.g. `this.formSubmitting`, which will be `false` by default. When you submit the form, call a function on the onSubmit event, which will set `this.formSubmitting = true`. When your HTTP call is done, set `this.formSubmitting = false` again.

Comment: i have to create directive which help to disable the button until form get submitted and responded. once we get response from server we may enable it

Comment: @ShubhamYerawar, I need to create directive which have isolated scope. we need to handle at interceptor.

Comment: @Aaaron, what ever you said wiill work for one form one button, how do we create as directive so that it can be worked as plug in play

Comment: You need to implemente a observable like your code, but need a promisse from the back-end, when returns `resolve`, you enable/disable the buttom again

Comment: @gauti have you found a solution for this. If so, can you please share how did you have implemented it.

Comment: @ramkris, I have implemented the methodology of how callback work in javascript, i  have individual subscribe in each controller which work as a isolated scope

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` and pass the flag `true` or `false`. This will easily enable/disable your button. Pass value `true/false` flag from your `.ts` file.

```
<button *ngIf="flag"> Submit<button>
```

Comment: when i do that multiple button, how we track what response for what button ?

Comment: @gauti best with promises for each http call and wait till they are resolved.